# Authorization Required in certain Google Sheets users & Script Migrated from Rhino to V8

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth, v8, rhino

My company utilizes Google sheets partially as an inventory system, I am not part of IT but need these sheets to function.
[Rhino to V8 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9rOm.jpg)

The top of our scripts shows the message **"This script has been successfully migrated from Rhino to V8 runtime on Mar 8, 2023"**
Can someone convert our Rhino code to V8?

```
function copyAndDelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fcR4QMM2TlKDju9prj4UiUR0-oS3YZ0TdeoPS_LWYWc');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Roll Film");
  var copyRange = sheet.getRange("h4:h44");
  var l = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().length;

  var pasteRange = sheet.getRange("Roll Film!F4:F44");
  pasteRange.setValues(copyRange.getValues());
  copyRange.setFormula("=(f4-i4+g4)");

  var clearadd = sheet.getRange("Roll Film!g4:g44");
  clearadd.setValue("0")

  var cleartaken = sheet.getRange("Roll Film!I4:I44");
  cleartaken.setValue("0")

  };
```

I am able to update Google sheets with no issues but others are having issues due to authorization requirement tied to their account even with editor rights. I need help converting code from Rhino to V8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copyAndDelete() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fcR4QMM2TlKDju9prj4UiUR0-oS3YZ0TdeoPS_LWYWc');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Roll Film");
  var rg = sh.getRange("h4:h44");
  var prg = sh.getRange("F4:F44");
  prg.setValues(rg.getValues());
  rg.setFormula("=(f4-i4+g4)");
  sh.getRange("g4:g44").setValue("0")
  sh.getRange("I4:I44").setValue("0")
}
```